# Key Value Pairs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array of strings array `['one','two',three']` and would like to transform this into a key value pair so that it looks like (first element is the key and last element the value):

```
{
  one:'three'
}
```

This is how far I've gotten:

```
function t(array) {
var key = array[0];
return {key:array[array.length-1]}
}
```

output:

```
{ key: 'three' }
```

The value is correct but the key is not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need square bracket around `key` to evaluate its content as the key of the object:

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

function t(array) {
  var key = array[0];
  return { [key]:array[array.length-1] }
}

console.log(t(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use square bracket while accessing properties using variables

```js
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three ']

function t(array) {
  var key = array[0];
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = array[array.length - 1]
  return obj;
}
console.log(t(array))
```